# Displaying uploaded images in alpaca js

Tags: javascript, jquery, alpacajs

I have this object

```
{
    "files": [{
        "name": "713311.png",
        "size": false,
        "deleteUrl": "https://example.com/file_uploads/uploads/713311.png",
        "deleteType": "DELETE"
    }, {
        "name": "1008112.png",
        "size": false,
        "deleteUrl": "https://example.com/file_uploads/uploads/1008112.png",
        "deleteType": "DELETE"
    }, {
        "name": "1048333.png",
        "size": false,
        "deleteUrl": "https://example.com/file_uploads/uploads/1048333.png",
        "deleteType": "DELETE"
    }, {
        "name": "1768201.png",
        "size": false,
        "deleteUrl": "https://example.com/file_uploads/uploads/1768201.png",
        "deleteType": "DELETE"
    }],
    "name": "John Matrix",
    "age": 40,
    "images": "no images",
    "ice": "Mint",
    "condition": "Refurbished",
    "array_data": [{
        "flavor": "strawberry",
        "topping": "nuts"
    }, {
        "flavor": "chocolate",
        "topping": "raisin"
    }],
    "description_required": "Y",
    "printer_type": "Laser Jet",
    "description": "<p><strong>This is a very good description</strong></p>",
    "color": "Blue"
}
```

that i have posted from my form and saved it in my remote server. I then obtain the object using ajax and try and display the images

in postRender

```
"postRender": function() {
$.get("http://localhost:8000/data_routes/fetch_edit_data", function(response){
form.data = response;
    console.log('Mounted Lifecycle Method', response );
    console.log('After Edit Data Inserted', form.data );
    let remoteData = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log('Remote Data', typeof response );
    //Object.assign(form.data, remoteData);
    $('#form').alpaca().setValue(remoteData);
  });
  
}
```

Every other data is displayed but the images are not.  I am using image upload functionality http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/fields/upload.html

Why are my images not being displayed?

Comment: I am unable to see the `deleteUrl` index in the link you have given. Check which form you are using and use the same data structure that they have given under that form.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by `deleteUrl index in the link you have given` The data i have shown is literally everything i am posting from the client.

Comment: I added some image indexes https://jsfiddle.net/dpkbteLh/1/